# Evaluating functions at several points

Tags: wolfram-mathematica

I want to evaluate f[x,y]=-4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2 at points (1,-2); (2,-3); (3,-2); (2,-1).

I tried using *Outer* but for some reason it does not give me actual values. Help.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Remember that Mathematica has a specific way of defining functions. In your case it would be `f[x_,y_]:=-4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2`. Then you could simply use `f[1,-2]` etc.

Comment: I tried that way, but the output I get is a little graph of that function and values I used next to it.

Comment: Really? It should just return a number. Did you remember the underscores in f[x_,y_], and the ":=" instead of "="?

Comment: I tried your way today and it worked. Do not know what was wrong or different yesterday. Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

Perhaps consider using a 'pure' function. For example:

```
-4 #1 + #1^2 - 4*#2 - #2^2 & @@@ {{1, -2}, {2, -3}, {3, -2}, {2, -1}}
```

gives

{1, -1, 1, -1}

Comment: @Dostre.  You probably are already aware of this, but another possibility is replacement rules.  For example: `-4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2 /. Thread[{x, y} -> #] & /@ {{1, -2}, {2, -3}, {3, -2}, {2, -1}}` or, for an individual case, `-4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2 /. {x -> 1, y -> -2}`.

Comment: Yep thanks for pointing this out. Now, I can choose the way I consider convenient from the bunch posted here. This makes this thread more complete. Thanks again

Answer (score 4):

Here are some variations on the theme:

```
Clear[f]

f[{x_, y_}] := -4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2
points = {{1, -2}, {2, -3}, {3, -2}, {2, -1}};
Map[f, points]
```

{1, -1, 1, -1}

```
f[x_, y_] := -4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2
f[1, -2]
```

1

```
f = Function[{x, y}, -4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2];
f[1, -2]
```

1

Answer (score 3):

You can use functions like `Apply` and `Map` to evaluate a function in a list of points, for example

```
f[x_, y_] := -4 x + x^2 - 4 y - y^2 

pts =  {{1, -2}, {2, -3}, {3, -2}, {2, -1}};

Apply[f, pts, {1}]

(* out: {1, -1, 1, -1} *)
```

or using `@@@` as a short hand for `Apply[ ...., {1}]`

```
f @@@ pts
```